# Paypal Rest API - How to get client ID and secret?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, omnipay

I am considering using implementing Paypal Rest API using using [Omnipay: PayPal](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal) package - PayPal_Rest (Paypal Rest API).

Where do I ask client to find client ID and Secret Key from their PayPal account so they can enter on our backend in order to use Paypal Method for their eCommerce site?

I am even struggling to find one from my personal Paypal Account.

Comment: All the API keys can be found in the sections metioned here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PayPal API credentials can be found at https://developer.paypal.com/.

1. Go to https://developer.paypal.com/ sign in with your PayPal account
2. If you aren't automatically redirected to the developer dashboard, click your name in the top right corner and click Dashboard
3. Scroll down to "REST API apps" and click "Create app"
4. Once created, you will be able to see client id and secret